# Why does the while loop keep running?

Tags: while-loop, pine-script

in the script below one of the `and` conditions of the `while` loop turns false when `i = 1` (if run on a bar 2 bars after t1).  However, the loop keeps running. Why? Must be something really obvious...

(when using  just `i` instead of `i+2` everything works just fine)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

t1 = input.time(timestamp("10 December 2023 15:00"), "Time")

bgcolor(time == t1 ? color.rgb(247, 164, 164, 68) : na)

if time == t1
    label.new(x = bar_index,y = high * 1.05, text = str.format("t1 =\n{1, date, short} {1, time, short}\nbar_index =\n{0}", bar_index, t1), color = color.yellow, style = label.style_label_down)

i = 0 
while (t1 <= (time[i+2])) and i< 100 //and sl > low
    log.info("\ni+2 = {0}, bi[i+2] = {3}
                          , \ntime[i+2] = {1, date, short} {1, time, short}
                          , \n(t1 <= time[i+2]) is {2}
                          "
                          , i+2
                          , time[i+2]
                          , t1  <= time[i+2]
                          , bar_index - (i+2)
                          )


    i+=1

if t1 == timestamp(2023, 10, 30, 7, 0)
    log.info("\nLOOP ENDED: \ni = {0}
                          , \nt1 = {1, date, short} {1, time, short}
                          , \ntime[i+2] = {2, date, short} {2, time, short}
                          , \n(t1 <= time[i+2]) is {3}
                          "
                          , i
                          , t1
                          , time[i+2]
                          , t1 <= time[i+2]
                          )
plotchar(display = display.data_window, location = location.top, char = "",  series = bar_index                     , title =  "bar_index"                      )
```

Please see the screenshot: [image]